# makepkg error "failed to create the directory $BUILDDIR"

Tags: archlinux

Title explains it all really. Whenever I try to makepkg in a directory in non-root I get the previous error followed by "An unknwon error has occured. Exiting...".

Comment: Which package? All packages? The title really does not explain it all. Also, you may be better served posting this on a *nix-specific forum. Stackoverflow is more aimed towards programming

Comment: I figured another forum for arch linux would have been better, although I also figured this may conenside with programming a bit--no? Either way all packages fail to install.

Comment: Why does makepkg try to create the current directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error when trying to install yaourt on a clean install of arch, what fixed it was changing write permissions with:

sudo chmod a+w

Comment: This helped along with the the solution below regarding directory location. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/scripts/libmakepkg/util/util.sh.in?h=v5.1.0#n88 and means that the directory referred to by the BUILDDIR variable documented in the [makepkg.conf(5)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.conf.5.html#_options) manpage, does not exist and you don't have permissions to create it.

So... figure out where this is being set, and fix that.

Note also that the full error message provided by makepkg would include the directory which could not be created, in parentheses after the text of your title. So not only does the title not say it all, it is missing the debugging information specifically added by the developers in order to help users solve the issue as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to install yay. **yay does not like to run as root, or under the /root folder** (directly or not directly).  The problem was that I tried to do everything under /root directory: cloned the yay git package into /root/downloads, then **chown** the git file (and directory) to user arch, then switched user to arch (su arch), then tried to run makepkg... The solution was simple - **switch to arch user first**:

```
su arch
cd /home/arch
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
cd yay
makepkg -si
```

Answer (score 0):

his issue comes up in a search—you are most likely trying to run `makepkg` somewhere outside your home directory, where you do not have permissions.

Move the `PKGBUILD` (and any associated files) somewhere under another folder like Download or ..... try 100% work.